# R: Aggregating Large Data Frame under a Grouping Condition

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, aggregate, data.table

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to aggregate a large data frame (about 50M rows) that looks similar to:

```
>sample_frame = data.frame("id" = rep(sample(1:100,2,replace=F),3),
+ "date" = sample(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2014-02-13"),by=1),6),
+ "value" = runif(6))
> sample_frame
  id       date      value
1 73 2014-02-11 0.84197491
2  7 2014-01-14 0.08057893
3 73 2014-01-16 0.78521616
4  7 2014-01-24 0.61889286
5 73 2014-02-06 0.54792356
6  7 2014-01-06 0.66484848
```

Here we have 2 unique IDs with 3 dates and a value assigned to each.  I know that I can use ddply, or data.table, or just a lapply to aggregate and find the mean for each ID.

What I'm really looking for is a way to quickly find the mean for each ID for the most recent two dates.  For example, with sapply:

```
> sapply(split(sample_frame,sample_frame$id),function(x){
+   mean(x$value[x$date%in%x$date[order(x$date,decreasing=T)][1:2]])
+ })
        7        73 
0.3497359 0.6949492
```

I can't figure out how to get data.table to do this.  Thoughts? Hints?

Comment: Good question, sorry about not being clear.  Yes the dates should be unique for each ID.  If there are groups with 1 row only, just the row's value should be returned.

Comment: No NA values, the data are clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `tail` in your "data.table" aggregation step?

```
set.seed(1)
sample_frame = data.frame("id" = rep(sample(1:100,2,replace=F),3),
                          "date" = sample(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),
                                              as.Date("2014-02-13"),by=1),6),
                          "value" = runif(6))

DT <- data.table(sample_frame, key = "id,date")
DT
#    id       date      value
# 1: 27 2014-01-09 0.20597457
# 2: 27 2014-01-26 0.62911404
# 3: 27 2014-02-07 0.68702285
# 4: 37 2014-02-06 0.17655675
# 5: 37 2014-02-09 0.06178627
# 6: 37 2014-02-13 0.38410372
DT[, mean(tail(value, 2)), by = id]
#    id        V1
# 1: 27 0.6580684
# 2: 37 0.2229450
```

---

Since you require the mean of just two values, you can do it directly (without using `mean`). And you can use the internal variable `.N` instead of tail to get more speed-up. You just have to take care of the case where there's just 1 date. Basically, this should be much faster.

```
DT[, (value[.N]+value[max(1L, .N-1)])/2, by=id]
```